# SIGSEGV fault when opening file

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

On line 42 I receive the signal `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation Fault`.

From the research I did, I believe it has something to do with my pointers, but I really don't know what.

Here is the call stack during the debug:

```
#0 7560ECC0 strxfrm_l() (C:\windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll:??)
#1 75665864 putwchar() (C:\windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll:??)
#2 756658D4 msvcrt!fscanf() (C:\windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll:??)
#3 00401494 readFile(filename=0x404024 <_Jv_RegisterClasses+4210724> "C:\\input.txt", seed=0x75601162 <onexit+53>, minSize=0x75655bc4 <msvcrt!atexit+13>, maxSize=0x401ef0 <__do_global_dtors>, count=0x28ff94) (C:\Users\xxxxx\Dropbox\School\Spring 13\Computer Sci\Project 4_Pxxxxxx\main.c:42)
#4 00401375 main() (C:\Users\xxxxx\Dropbox\School\Spring 13\Computer Sci\Project 4_Pxxxxxxxx\main.c:28)
```

Relevant code:

Here is the main():

```
int main()
{
    int array[4], min, max, Ans, avg, count;

    readFile("C:\\input.txt", array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]);
    validateInput(array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]);
    generateNumbers(array, array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]);
    calculateStatistics(array, 4, min, max, Ans, avg);
    printReport(array, 4, array[1], count, min, max, Ans, avg);

}
```

---

```
35 bool readFile(char *filename, int *seed, int *minSize, int *maxSize, int *count)
36 {
37    int readCount;
38    FILE *fp; // FILE must be ALL CAPS
39    bool status = true;
40
41    fp=fopen("input.txt", "r"); // Opens the file for reading
42    readCount = fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %d", seed, minSize, maxSize, count);
43    if(readCount != 4)
44    {
45        printf("At least one of the supplied values is invalid.\n");
46        status = false;
47    }
48    fclose(fp); // Closes the file
49    return status;
50 }
```

What the program is trying to do is open that file and pass the values into another function to generate an array of random numbers.

Comment: `fopen` probably fails and `fp` is `NULL`. Or one of the pointers you're passing is wrong.

Comment: You are passing in a "filename" param but are not using it. Is that intentional?

Comment: That filename should really be `const char *`, by the way.

Comment: Show us the implementation of the `main` function.  I think one of your pointers is invalid.

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, fopen with mode 'r' will fail and returnNULL. You have to check for that error.

Comment: +1 for the line numbers! 8-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
readFile("C:\\input.txt", array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]);
```

is the culprit.  You are passing the values instead of pointers to the values.  Try this:

```
readFile("C:\\input.txt", &array[0], &array[1], &array[2], &array[3]);
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks Jeremy!
I really need to work on my pointers

Comment: @alk Yes, I was just thinking that myself.  There should be *at least* a warning.

Comment: @user2053164: Sometimes following the warnings already helps! ;-)